# Quickly send an interprocess signal

Tags: c#, c++, signals, interprocess

I want to send a signal from a C++ application to a C# application. This is only to let the C# program know the other one is running. I already use C# but I'm not really good at C++ yet. Do I have to create pipes or is there a quicker and/or easier way to do this?

Comment: A named pipe is probably the easiest solution, sockets would work as well but are more complicated

Comment: Use a Windows named event.

Answer (score 0):

IPC is easy using the classic WM_COPYDATA. A good example can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22402/Interprocess-Communication-Between-NET-and-MFC-Usi).